# How do I count booting time?

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, centos, libvirt

So I have different virtual machines in different storage types and I'm trying to do a comparison of different things. One of which is booting time. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the virtual machines are Linux-based and using systemd as init service, you can use `systemd-analyze`:

```
[computer user]# systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 17.258s (kernel) + 5.936s (userspace) = 23.194s
```

With `systemd-analyze blame` you can even check out which service took the most time:

```
[computer user]# systemd-analyze blame
    4min 47.840s updatedb.service
          2.539s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptsda1.service
          2.257s plymouth-start.service
          2.089s systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-cryptsda1.service
          1.351s man-db.service
```

You can even plot the boot process in a SVG graphic:

```
systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg
```